# Javascript Indent issue in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

I'm using sublime text 3 and recently i'm facing indentation issue in multiple select indent. It only happen in javascript files or embeded javascript in html.

[image: Javascript Indent Issue in Sublime Text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the trick for that question. Ctrl+[ and Ctrl+] can be used as well for indentation but i want my tab key to behave like Ctrl+] just like Shift+tab does as Ctrl+[